# Why does parsing '23:00 PM' with SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa") return 11 a.m.?

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

Why does parsing '23:00 PM' with `SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa")` return 11 a.m.?

Comment: yeah...that question doesn't even make sense. garbage in, garbage out. you're probably right that it adds 12 hours internally for 'pm'.

Comment: @Peter: Well I KNOW THAT!! I actually discover what the problem was after a few minutes. That's not the question here. ( Have you ever debugged someone else code? Then it will make sense. )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be getting an exception, since "23:00 PM" is not a valid string, but Java's date/time facility is [lenient](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient(boolean)) by default, when handling date parsing.

The logic is that 23:00 PM is 12 hours after 11:00 PM, which is 11:00 AM the following day. You'll also see things like "April 31" being parsed as "May 1" (one day after April 30).

If you don't want this behavior, set the lenient property to false on your SimpleDateFormat using [DateFormat#setLenient(boolean)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)), and you'll get an exception when passing in invalid date/times.

Comment: Ohh, I've seen that flag before, and never knew that was it all about. :P ( nor care about it )

Answer (score 17):

You want "HH:mm aa" as your format, if you will be parsing 24-hour time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
    final Date date = df.parse("23:00 PM");
    System.out.println("date = " + df.format(date));
}
```

outputs

```
date = 23:00 PM
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa"); is giving lint warning ..
do you have idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Satyam, what's the warning?

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried `HH:mm aa`?

`HH` is for 24 hour while `hh` is for 12.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the formatting options specifed in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
H     Hour in day (0-23)    
k   Hour in day (1-24)  
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

Notice that "h" would be for hours 1-12.  If you want to handle 1-24, try "k".  for 0-23 try "H".  But I would not expect valid results if you are putting in impossible data.

Answer (score 2):

23:00 PM could be thought of as 11 AM *the next day*.  Javascript and PHP work like this pretty much but I can't speak for Java.

Comment: That's what I looks it's happening. Yeap!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it does something like:

```
hours = hours % 12;
```

to ensure that the hours are in the proper range.