# ParseException when trying to parse Date string

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing, datetime-parsing

I have a piece of code written to parse date string -

```
    DateFormat cal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    cal.setLenient(false);
    try {
        cal.parse("2018-01-01 14:42");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get an exception saying -

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-01-01 14:42"
at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:388)
at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:10)
```

I am not sure why I am seeing this error as the date string and the format given is right. Please help

Comment: use `HH` not `hh`

Comment: @YCF_L - Good eye. I missed it it.

Comment: or maybe just `LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01 14:42".replace(' ', 'T'));`

Comment: For your own best, drop `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, they are long outdated and have proven unnecessarily troublesome to work with. java.time, the modern Java date and timme API, is so much nicer.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many times already. You would have found working code examples to compare to your faulty code.

Comment: Related: [Why does parsing '23:00 PM' with SimpleDateFormat(“hh:mm aa”) return 11 a.m.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154903/why-does-parsing-2300-pm-with-simpledateformathhmm-aa-return-11-a-m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html:

Lowercase h in the `SimpleDateFormat` indicates hour in the 12 hour format, whereas 24-hour format is indicated with uppercase H. As 14 > 12, the date 14:42 fails to be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

`hh` is used for the time of the day with hours going from 1 to 12. 14 is not a valid hour for this kind of hour-representation, so you have to use `HH` or `kk`. The former is used for times that are shown from 0-23, the latter for times shown between 1-24. Most likely you have to use `HH` or `H`/`k` if the single digit hours aren't preceded by a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `HH` instead of `hh` for hour pattern if the hour is displayed in 24 hour format. 
See the documentation below for more information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

```
    DateTimeFormatter cal = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm");
    LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01 14:42", cal);
```

This runs without exception or other error.

### java.time

The date-time classes you use, `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`, are long outdated and furthermore notoriously troublesome. I recommend you stop using them immediately. Instead use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It came out nearly four years ago after having been described in Java Specification Request (JSR) 310 (a name that somehow still clings to the API).

As others have correctly pointed out, your error was that you used lowercase `hh` in your format pattern string, where you should have used uppercase `HH` for hour of day. Just one little example of where the modern classes try to be more helpful, try the same. If I insert `hh` in the format pattern in the code above, my program crashes (because there is no try-catch construct) with an `DateTimeParseException` with the following message:

> Text '2018-01-01 14:42' could not be parsed: Invalid value for
>   ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 14

While perhaps still a bit esoteric, it is very precise. And I would dare hope that in combination with the documentation it would tell you what you did wrong.

The exception is unchecked, so no try-catch is required around the parsing. On the other hand, you may use one if you like (and if you are not very certain that the format of your date-time string is correct, you should).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern date and time API was first described.